# Understanding oAuth implicit flow

Tags: oauth, twitch

I'm working with the New Twitch API and I wish to get data from and end point using javascript.

Endpoint https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference/#get-streams

For the means of testing, I'm hitting the endpoint with Postman and it's working.

According to the docs, I need to provide a `client-id` which I can get from my developer dashboard and I add this as a header in Postman.

What I'm confused about is that it seems for as long as you have someones `client-id` *(which is going to be exposed when using JS)* anyone can hit this endpoint? What stops someone taking my `client-id` or me taking someone elses and using it for their/my own purposes and what are the risks with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In general, it's the `Redirection URL` that's the lynchpin.

The flow works like this:

1. You register your app at Twitch.  As part of this step, you specify your `redirection URL` (https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/#registration)
2. A user visits a web page that makes use of the API
3. The user needs to authenticate.  The web page hands off to the Twitch OAUTH authentication page, passing along its `Client ID`
4. The user authenticates with Twitch
5. Twitch redirects the user to the `Redirection URL` set up in step #1, along with a `Bearer Token`.

As you can see in step 5, the token is only sent back to **your** `Redirection URL.`  If another website tried to get a user authenticated using your `Client ID` they would never receive back the token.

The area I think you could run into trouble is rate limiting.  Twitch limits you to 30 queries per minute with a `Client ID` and no `Bearer Token` or 120 queries per minute with both.  If a malicious user is using your Client ID then it would eat up your rate limit.  https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/guide/